# How to add unallocated space to home partition after Windows removal

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ssd

I have read most of the answers and tried them but nothing happened. I need to add unallocated space to home partition after removing Windows 10.

If I want to use Kali Linux on VirtualBox, which partition do I install it in?

[image: Picture of GParted listing device partitions]

I have a 120GB SSD that is used for the system.

Comment: There is no way to add unallocated space to home (/dev/sda5) without moving partitions, because /dev/sda4 is in the way. It's strange that "most of the answer" didn't mention that.

Comment: Also moving the root partition could cause boot errors. The best option I see is make a data partition with the free space and mount that to a folder in /home.  PS the MS reserved partition can be deleted also.

Comment: As long as you reinstall the bootloader, you should be fine. But given the small amount of data on /home, I'd back it up, and do a reinstall. A 10$ memory stick will hold 16GB data. Get two or three for redundancy...

Comment: You have to do it in steps. Backup first in case there are problems. Move sdb4 to the right -> apply changes . Unallocated space will then be adjacent to /home. Then resize sdb5 . Moving partitions should not cause problems with boot.

Comment: I don't know what to do . I will reinstall ubuntu at the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

---

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

---

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sdb4 all the way left
- **move** sdb5 all the way left
- note: Now is the time to think about creating a swap partition if desired... don't **resize** sdb5 all the way right, leave some room.
- **resize** the right side of sdb5 all the way right
- click the `Apply` icon

Comment: thank U for your effort i will reinstall ubuntu as soon as I can